# Laravel 8, Passport and MongoDB integration

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-passport

I am having difficulties integrating Laravel 8, Passport and MongoDB.

```
"laravel/passport": "^10.1",
"jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.8",
```

and to connect those two I read about using another package called:

```
designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport
```

which has current version "2.0.1" and does not support Laravel 8, and when I try
to install the package this is the error message:

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport[v2.0.1]
- designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport v2.0.0 requires jenssegers/mongodb 3.3.* || 3.4.* || 3.5.* || 3.6.* -> found jenssegers/mongodb[v3.3.0-alpha, ..., 3.6.x-dev] but it confli
cts with your root composer.json require (^3.8)
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated, have in mind I am beginner in Laravel, and had
quite a bit problems using MongoDB. This is my last point for help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By upgrading to `php 8.0` and using the last version of `mongodb driver (1.11.0)`, I've solved the problem.